# custom ADO.NET data provider with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net

I am writing an application that connect to ESRI's File Geodatabase, which is a proprietary database.
I found a custom ADO.NET data provider for this File Geodatabase.
I like to access this database with NHibernate.
Can I use this ADO.NET data provider with NHibernate without writing any customization code for NHibernate?
is there a driver that deal with generic ado.net provider?
so far what I found, they told me to implement IDriver, and IDialect in order to acheive that.
And in case I have to write my own implementation, is there any document that describe how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `GenericDialect` (not quite full-featured, as few things are less standard than SQL), but you need to implement a driver so NH can connect to the db.

You can take any of the simpler drivers in https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Driver as a starting point.